# How to use jQuery Touch Punch

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-touch-punch

For jQuery Touch Punch, you have to download jquery.ui.touch-punch.js. I was wondering where do I have to put this file?

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Also the second step of implementing it is

`Include Touch Punch after jQuery UI and before its first use.`

Why do I have to include it before and after and not just before?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misread the documentation. It just means that you have to load JQuery UI before you load Touch Punch, and obviously, Touch Punch must be loaded before you use any of it's features.

Basically your HTML file should look something like this:

```
<html>
     <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Content-->
    <script>
        /*Javascript actually using touch punch*/
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```